# Looking for a function given these inputs and ouputs

Tags: functions

What is the function f(x)= that produces these discrete values:

```
input   output
[0-1500]     13
]1500-3000]  12
]3000-6000]  11
]6000-12000] 10
.....
```

**Update**: sorry for the lack of precision at the interval limits. Updated. Could you update your answers accordingly?

Thanks

Comment: Do the endpoints of the input intervals (e.g. 1500, 3000, 6000) belong to the set of smaller, or larger numbers?

Comment: Do you want a continuous function? If not, you can use step function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be computed as
$$x \mapsto \begin{cases}13 & 0 < x < 1500 \\
13 - \left\lceil \log_2(\frac{x}{1500}) \right\rceil & x \ge 1500 \end{cases} $$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the endpoints of the interval belong to the set of smaller numbers, so that $f((1500,3000]) = \{12\}$ and $f(1500) = 13$ , I'd use
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
13 & x \le 1500~~, \\
13 - \left\lceil \log_2 \frac{x}{1500} \right\rceil & \text{else}.
\end{cases}
$$
To implement the log, you can use $ \frac{\log x - \log 1500}{\log 2} $ . To switch the endpoints to the other interval, use a floor instead of a ceiling.

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. Gave the good answer to Henning because he answered a few seconds prior to you. Voted up yours for the log2 reminder.

Comment: @NicolasCadilhac Updated the answer as requested. Hope it works out for you!